# Bootstrap : hover event not working on media-body

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When i try to apply following on media-body nothing happens

```
.media:hover .media-body{
    background:#FEBD69;
}
```

where as if i replace media-body with media-left it starts working.

here is the plunk : https://plnkr.co/edit/NcSWBuACE8jlenHWMmWj?p=preview

Why hover does not work with media-body? Any solutions for achieving this

Comment: Can you do a demo ??

Comment: added the plunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. It will definitely work.

It's because you add     `background: #fcfcfc;` as a inline css.

You can override with adding `!important` like this.

```
.media:hover .media-body {
    background: #FEBD69 !important;
}
```